# How to append php file with jquery without click function?

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to append php files like objects but I need to do some calculations with them, so I can use include. Any other, bettery way is good aswell. (Do I need use ajax? How to use it?) `$('file_that_I_want_append.php').appendTo('.div_i_want_to_append_it_to');`

Comment: your looking for `.load` http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: $(document).readyhttp://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/ 

Read this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.load()`.

```
$('.div_i_want_to_append_it_to').load('file_that_I_want_append.php');
```

Just be sure to do this when the DOM is ready. If your scripts are in the `<head>` you will need to do this:

```
$(function() {
  $('.div_i_want_to_append_it_to').load('file_that_I_want_append.php');
});
```

Comment: I got empty .div_i_want_to_append_it_to. What I did wrong? it's inside fuction ready.

Comment: Make sure the selector is right. `$('.div_i_want_to_append_it_to')` would select `<div class="div_i_want_to_append_it_to"></div>` If that isn't the issue check out the Network tab in Chrome and make sure the request is being made and you're not just using the wrong file name.

Comment: thanks man, I was trying to figure it out all day, finally I realized that it wasn't class, but id. Still, there isn't any other SO threads about this current thing, they use onclicks everywere, I hope it will be useful for some other biginners like me.

Comment: Yeah, I see that mistake made often. Just brush up on your CSS selectors and it should help a lot.